# Updating state of the app without touching the DOM - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

I'm going through the Vue.js guide and I came across [**this**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input) paragraph. It says:

> Note in the method we simply update the state of our app without touching the DOM

Basically the method simply reverses a string on click of a button. What I'm unable to understand is the concept of `Updating the state of app` without touching the DOM. What does the state mean here? Can somebody explain this in layman terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the cornerstones of `Vue.js` is its simply implemented two-way data binding. This means that when a state or data value is changed within the `Vue` object/instance, it is also synced and changed in the DOM and vice versa without having to manually update both.

In a pure `Javascript` situation such as:

```js
function changeData() {
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "Second";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="data">First</span>
</div>

<button onclick="changeData()">Change Value</button>
```

In this, we are directly manipulating the DOM to change the text value of the `span` element, however, with `Vue's` two-way data binding, only the instance's state/data must be changed for both to update.

Answer (score 1):

If I really simplify it, then I would say that it's the **data** that's used for your application. Which includes, for example, your reversed string.

Or for example:

```
State: { isSwitchedOn: false }
UpdateStateFunc: (state, value) => state.isSwitchedOn = value;
```

So, we can update `isSwitchedOn` using `UpdateStateFunc`, but that doesn't mean we push that data to the DOM (ie. what's visible to the user). Making it visible to the user would be, perhaps, another function.